# Python import from class in different file

Tags: python-3.x, file, class, import

Here is my code in the main file:

```
from File2.Test import test

test()
```

And here is the code for the file containing the class:

```
class Test:
    def test(self):
        print('Test')
```

As you can see, I don't just want to import the class, I want to import something from the class. When I try the syntax above, I get this error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'File2.Test'; 'File2' is not a package`. If there is anyway to just import `test()` from File2, please let me know. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from File2.Test import test

Python interprets this as you asking for a function called `test` from a file called `Test.py` in a directory called `File2` (which also happens to have an `__init_.py`), thinking that `File2` is a package.

Rather, you are trying to import a class method from a different file. The preferred way of calling such a method is to import the class definition and the call the method fromt eh class:

```
from File2 import Test

test = Test.test
```

Now, you have a way of calling `test`. However, as long as `test` is not static, you'll run into issues in actually calling it